# find and delete folder and/or zip file in a directory

Tags: bash, find

let's say I have a directory like this:

```
IIS1
IIS1-DVLP
FS
IIS1.zip
IIS1-DVLP.zip
RA.zip
```

the top 3 entries are folders, the bottom 3 entries are zip files.

If I now want to delete `IIS1` and `IIS1.zip` I tried the following:

```
admin@Server:/volumeUSB1/usbshare1-2$ find -name "IIS1" -o -name "IIS1.zip"
./IIS1
./IIS1.zip
```

which found me the things I want to delete, so I simply thought I can add my `-delete`

```
admin@Server:/volumeUSB1/usbshare1-2$ find -name "IIS1" -o -name "IIS1.zip" -delete
admin@Server:/volumeUSB1/usbshare1-2$ ls -l
total 1
drwxrwxrwx 1 admin users   0 Feb 11 14:03 IIS1
drwxrwxrwx 1 admin users   0 Feb 11 14:03 IIS1-DVLP
-rwxrwxrwx 1 admin users 164 Feb 11 14:03 IIS1-DVLP.zip
```

but my folder somehow survived!

How would I do it in this case? I can't use a Wildcard `*` because `IIS1-DVLP` would also match that wildcard

This folder only has subfolders or zip files in it. either both things exist (like as for `IIS1`) or only a folder or only a zip file. I want to be able to delete whatever exists.

Comment: This is a precedence problem; the `-o` binds the `-delete` to only one side of the "or".

Comment: @tripleee so much to leeeeaaaarn aaah. ok thanks. since this was so easy to answer, should I delete the question or do you want to expand it to an answer?

Comment: Just leave it, duplicates which take this long to find (6 minutes!!!) will probably benefit from having duplicates which phrase the question in a different manner.

Comment: @tripleee I mean I know what you mean by duplicate, but I don't really think this is a duplicate, since I knew how to find them, i simply didn't know that the `-delete` is only for the right hand side of `-o`, which is fascinating btw. Bash and PowerShell (the only thing I know well) are so completely different